# Should I use many to many relationship?

Tags: sql, many-to-many, entity-relationship

I am working on a university project for a library and I have a table USERS with a column
ROLES ( possible values: member, librarian, admin).

I've always heard that I shouldn't use many to many relationships. The reason such a relationship exists here is because a LOAN has user_id for the borrower and Id for the Librarian that was working at the time. (Table LOAN connects to table BOOK with other relationships as authors and genre etc. not needed for this question)

**QUESTION**

I don't see a way or a point to split this relationship in a many-to-one and one-to-many. Is what I am doing wrong for some reason?

**Edit***: Forgot to add FK in my diagram for Librarian_borrowed, Librarian_returned, but they are FK's. Also a librarian can also borrow a book.

Thank you for your time.

P.S. I've thought about splitting the table USERS or using generalization, but I don't see any real benefits and I quite like it this way, keeps things easier for my project. This is not my question but I'm sure someone might comment on it.

[image: E/R Diagram]

Comment: This is a good question. This is not a many-to-many relationship, as one loan refers to one borrower and one librarian only. Tis means you must not draw an m:n line here. I suppose this would be modelled with two lines, one for each relationship in ERM.

Comment: Thank you, that's a good observation. I should do that to make things clear.

Answer (score 0):

No need for m2m relationships. You need to add multiple FKs to LOAN table, one for each relationship to the USER table e.g. borrower_id, librarian_id, etc.

They will each reference a different user record (unless, of course the librarian also borrows a book)

Comment: Yes a librarian can also borrow a book. Do you think this design is faulty?

Comment: If the number of entities related to loan is not finite (configurable/dynamic), you could use an XRef table such as LoanUserRelationshipXref with a Relationship table.

[User] <== [LoanUserRelationshipXref (UserId, LoanId, RelationshipId)] ==> [Loan]

Comment: @GregOgle So have a table for defining the relationship with a column with e.x. possible values ("borrower, librarian_that_loaned, librarian_that_received)? Sounds nice and cleaner. What would be the benefit of doing that? I only think it will slow down reading and writting.

Comment: I think the design is okay. One user lends the book, one user borrows the book. That the borrowing user can be a librarian doesn't make a difference. The only issue is that it may be a little difficult to ensure the lending user is a librarian. You could go about this with an additional librarian table where only users reside who are librarians. That would make the relationships clearer. It's a design choice to make and both options are valid approaches in my opinion.

Comment: Well, thinking about this, maybe it's a good idea to split users further into different tables anyway. A librarian should have some employee number, while a member has a member ID. An admin has neither. You may also want a member's private telephone and credit card number, while you don't need it for the employed librarian and the admin. Etc. So while they are all users in your database, they are very different from each other, so making them different entities sounds reasonable.

Comment: If you want to record the roles that a user can play (and possible use that information to restrict what users can do) then that would be a case for a M:M table - but between USERS and a new ROLES TABLE

Comment: The design I mentioned would support dynamically adding relationships. If the relationships are finite, what you have is good.

Comment: I agree with NickW about assigning roles to users rather than splitting them across tables. It is nice to have a consistent place to go to find all users. Can tie into security (permission/role) model too.